# Проверка формы по заданному условию

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня есть небольшая форма, поля которой я проверяю. Мне необходимо организовать проверку если пользователь заполняет первые два инпута с типом текст и один инпут с типом файл, то данные отправляются, иначе ошибка, и такой  вариант, если пользовватель не выбирает файл, то он должен заполнить все 11 полей с типом текст, иначе тоже ошибка. Подскажите, что я делаю не правильно?

```js
$("form").eq($indx_form).on("click", $el, function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var data = new FormData(document.forms[1]);
        data.append( 'file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0] );

        var cnt=0;
        var first_three= $("#conclusion-treaty input:lt(2)");

        $('#conclusion-treaty input[type="text"]').each(function(i){
           val=$(this).val();
            
           if(val.length!=0 || val.length!="" || val.length!="undefined") cnt++
           console.log(cnt,i)
        })
        
        if( (cnt != 11 ) || ( (first_three.length!=2) || ( $("input[type=file]").val()=="") ) ){
            $(".info_block").html("Вы не заполнили поля");
            console.log(cnt)
        }
        else {
            $(".info_block").html("Ваше сообщение отправлено");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                url: "read.php",
                data: {data},
                success: function(){
                    alert('Ваши данные оправленны');
                }
            })
            .done(function( file ) {
                console.log(file)
            });
           
        }

    });
```

```css
input{
  display:block;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="item1">
  <input type="text" name="item2">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="text" name="item3">
  <input type="text" name="item4">
  <input type="text" name="item5">
  <input type="text" name="item6">
  <input type="text" name="item7">
  <input type="text" name="item8">
  <input type="text" name="item9">
  <input type="text" name="item10">
  <input type="text" name="item11">
  <input type="submit" id="send">
</form>
```

Comment: Можете рассказать что такое #conclusion-treaty и почему такого элемента нет в прилагаемом коде? Ну и в целом у вас странный подход обработки submit. Нужно что то вроде `$("form").on("submit",function(e){})`

Answer (score 0):

Как я написал в комментарии, **первое** - есть проблема с вызовом submit 
Лучше это делать так `$("form").on("submit",function(e){})`

**Второй** момент в проверках - у вас неверное понимание работы выборки в Jquery.
`$("#conclusion-treaty input[type='text']:lt(11)").val == "")`
Вот этот кусок кода не будет делать то, что вы от него ожидаете. Потому что результат выборки - массив элементов и ответ val будет совсем другой, нежели значения инпутов. Проверить, что все элементы не пустые лучше все таки через цикл. Как собственно и другие проверки.

Возможно лучшее решение - это использование `function(indx, el){}` к вашей выборке с указанием функции для проверки на пустой элемент.

P.S а чтобы не писать костылей - лучше всего юзать готовые варианты - например validate JQuery (смотрим [Тут](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/))

Comment: изменил исходный код, проверку 11 инпутов сделал через цикл, но всё равно не работает

Comment: Потому что оно не знает где найти элемент #conclusion-treaty. Если это какой-то родительский элемент то ладно. У вас хоть при дебаге внутрь  each заходит?